# Как правильно создать стандартную сетку flexbox?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим вот такой код

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner-content"></div>
    <div class="inner-sidebar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Как правильно использовать `flexbox`? Нужно сделать `main` контейнером? А внутри него `header`, `content` и `footer` сделать элементами контейнера? Если так можно ли потом сделать из `header`, `content`и footer тоже контейнеры. Или сразу `header`, `content`, `footer` делать контейнерами без `main` и работать с ними по отдельности.
И еще при работе с `flexbox` нужно ли делать кучу блоков в блоках, как при работе с `float`? Допустим создавать кучу `inner`

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="inner-header"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="inner-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="inner-sidebar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="inner-footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

допустим тут, удалите пожалуйста все, без чего лучше обойтись

Comment: Дело в том, что я уже несколько дней никак не могу разобраться, пересмотрел кучу роликов на ютубе, а сдавать работу уже скоро. Надеялся, что хоть тут подскажут

Comment: посмотрите как сделан этот фреймворк https://bulma.io/

Comment: Во-первых, не пнятно что такое `стандартная сетка`? От куда этот стандарт? Во-вторых, если имеется ввиду  `tag main`, не стоит его делать контейнером для  `header && footer`. Эти три новых тега `html5 - main, header && footer`, для этого и были созданы, чтобы быть остоной всего сайта... Конечно катострофы не будет, но это не грамотно и не правильно... И кстати  эти три тега должны быть единственными